# How do I use Powershell to add/remove references to a csproj?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, powershell, csproj

> In relation to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955964/possible-to-remove-and-add-a-reference-to-csproj-programmatically-via-a-batch-fi) I am trying to create a batch file which as part must remove and add a reference to an XML *.csproj file. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882762/nuget-uninstall-ps1-remove-a-project-reference), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745029/xpath-and-csproj), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136947/how-do-i-remove-an-xml-node-using-powershell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719460/powershell-xpath-selection) previous question but as a powershell n00b am unable to get it working (so far).

Can anyone help me with the following? I want to remove two specific references in a VS2010 csproj file (XML) and add a new reference.

I opened the csproj and the reference can be found at the following location

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!--          ...         -->
  <!-- Omitted for brevity  -->
  <!--          ...         -->

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'">
    <AvailableItemName Include="Effect" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SomeDirectory\SomeProjectFile.csproj">
      <Project>{AAB784E4-F8C6-4324-ABC0-6E9E0F73E575}</Project>
      <Name>SomeProject</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AnotherDirectory\AnotherProjectFile.csproj">
      <Project>{B0AA6A94-6784-4221-81F0-244A68C374C0}</Project>
      <Name>AnotherProject</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--          ...         -->
  <!-- Omitted for brevity  -->
  <!--          ...         -->

</Project>
```

Basically I want to:

- remove these two references
- insert a new reference to a pre-compiled DLL specified by relative path
- OR Add an Assembly Reference Location to the project specified by relative path

As a very simple example I have tried the following powershell script to delete all the ProjectReference nodes. I pass the path to csproj as argument. I get the error `Cannot validate the argument 'XML'. The Argument is null or empty`. I can confirm it *is* loading the csproj and saving it in-place unmodified so the path is correct.

```
param($path)
$MsbNS = @{msb = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}

function RemoveElement([xml]$Project, [string]$XPath, [switch]$SingleNode)
{
    $xml | Select-Xml -XPath $XPath | ForEach-Object{$_.Node.ParentNode.RemoveAll()}
}

$proj = [xml](Get-Content $path)
[System.Console]::WriteLine("Loaded project {0} into {1}", $path, $proj)

RemoveElement $proj "//ProjectReference" -SingleNode

    # Also tried
    # RemoveElement $proj "/Project/ItemGroup/ProjectReference[@Include=`'..\SomeDirectory\SomeProjectFile.csproj`']" -SingleNode
    # but complains cannot find XPath

$proj.Save($path)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any comments/suggestions welcome :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the problem is that your XML file has a default namespace `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"`. This causes problems with XPath. So you XPath `//ProjectReference` will return 0 nodes. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use a namespace manager.
2. Use namespace agnostic XPath.

Here's is how you could use a namespace manager:

```
$nsmgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $proj.NameTable
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('a','http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')
$nodes = $proj.SelectNodes('//a:ProjectReference', $nsmgr)
```

Or:

```
Select-Xml '//a:ProjectReference' -Namespace $nsmgr
```

Here's how to do it using namespace agnostic XPath:

```
$nodes = $proj.SelectNodes('//*[local-name()="ProjectReference"]')
```

Or:

```
$nodes = Select-Xml '//*[local-name()="ProjectReference"]'
```

The second approach can be dangerous because if there were more than one namespace it could select the wrong nodes but not it your case.

Comment: Wow, very helpful! Let me try this out. Thank you

Comment: first attempt, I called `proj.NameTable' and `nsmgr.AddNamespace` and got `System.Xml.Nametable doesn't contain a method named AddNamespace`

Comment: duh `[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $proj.NameTable` works. Ok working through this to remove the nodes. Seems to be selecting nodes without error

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson I should of noted this was untested. I updated my answer to fix that issue.

Comment: no worries, fixed. I created a powershell with the test XML above and played around with it until it removed it. Your AddNamespace was correct - with that it finds the node and can remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

> For posterities sake I will give the complete powershell scripts to add and remove references to csproj files. **Please vote up Andy Arismedi's answer if you find this useful** as he helped me find it. Feel free to give me a +1 also while you're at it ;-)

**AddReference.ps1**

```
# Calling convension:
#   AddReference.PS1 "Mycsproj.csproj", 
#                    "MyNewDllToReference.dll", 
#                    "MyNewDllToReference"
param([String]$path, [String]$dllRef, [String]$refName)

$proj = [xml](Get-Content $path)
[System.Console]::WriteLine("")
[System.Console]::WriteLine("AddReference {0} on {1}", $refName, $path)

# Create the following hierarchy
#  <Reference Include='{0}'>
#     <HintPath>{1}</HintPath>
#  </Reference>
# where (0) is $refName and {1} is $dllRef

$xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
$itemGroup = $proj.CreateElement("ItemGroup", $xmlns);
$proj.Project.AppendChild($itemGroup);

$referenceNode = $proj.CreateElement("Reference", $xmlns);
$referenceNode.SetAttribute("Include", $refName);
$itemGroup.AppendChild($referenceNode)

$hintPath = $proj.CreateElement("HintPath", $xmlns);
$hintPath.InnerXml = $dllRef
$referenceNode.AppendChild($hintPath)

$proj.Save($path)
```

**RemoveReference.ps1**

```
# Calling Convention
#   RemoveReference.ps1 "MyCsProj.csproj" 
#   "..\SomeDirectory\SomeProjectReferenceToRemove.dll"
param($path, $Reference)

$XPath = [string]::Format("//a:ProjectReference[@Include='{0}']", $Reference)   

[System.Console]::WriteLine("");
[System.Console]::WriteLine("XPATH IS {0}", $XPath) 
[System.Console]::WriteLine("");

$proj = [xml](Get-Content $path)
[System.Console]::WriteLine("Loaded project {0} into {1}", $path, $proj)

[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $proj.NameTable
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('a','http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')
$node = $proj.SelectSingleNode($XPath, $nsmgr)

if (!$node)
{ 
    [System.Console]::WriteLine("");
    [System.Console]::WriteLine("Cannot find node with XPath {0}", $XPath) 
    [System.Console]::WriteLine("");
    exit
}

[System.Console]::WriteLine("Removing node {0}", $node)
$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node);

$proj.Save($path)
```

Comment: Just an FYI. Instead of `[system.console]::WriteLine` you can use the `Write-Host` cmdlet e.g. `Write-Host ("This is {0} typing" -f "less")` . `-f` is for string formatting :-)