# How to remove a reference in Visual Studio with PowerShell or command?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, command-line, nuget

I need to remove a reference from several projects in Visual Studio each time when I re/install/update a particular NuGet package that I cannot currently modify.

Is it possible to automate this process with `PowerShell` or a command?

It would also do if I just could execute it for each project by pasting it in the `Package Manager Console` instead of opening each one and deleting it manually.

Actually I need a similar functionality as the `Uninstall-Package` command but for a single reference. I had no luck looking for the source code of this command.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody on SO already did that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8967946/4606752) with powershell, he gives the scripts to add or remove references to a csproj.

If you want to do that while your solution is opened in Visual Studio, you can also do it using a Visual Studio Add-in.
Create an Add-in and add a reference to EnvDTE, Extensibility and VSLangProj.

Then here is some sample code to put in the Exec method to get you started:

```
foreach (Project project in _applicationObject.Solution.Projects)
{
    if (project.Object is VSLangProj.VSProject)
    {
        VSLangProj.VSProject vsproject = (VSLangProj.VSProject)project.Object;

        var reference = vsproject.References.Find("System.Xml");
        if (reference != null)
            reference.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, probably if I had looked for a csproj I could have found it too :) but I thought it would be some _standard_ Visual Studio API. I'm quite surprised you actually need to modify the project file by yourself.

Comment: Me too, that's why I suggested the add-in, this way it's a standard api and not some messing around in the csproj ;)

Comment: Still experimenting... I'll let you know when it works and mark it as answered :-)